# Where does eclipse store the settings for Navigator View configuration?

Tags: java, eclipse, view, workbench

Can it be setup globally per workspace and not per individual project ?

Answer (score 1):

They are stored in your workspace so yes, they can be setup per workspace.  Now, there are project configurations and such that could impact things displayed in the Navigator View but the actual configuration for the view itself is in your workspace.